# Hard Disk Space Shows in One Place, Shows Less in "Computer" Folder?

Tags: storage

I have 320 Hard Disk but in the picture in Computer Properties, it says capacity is 45GB. Which is obviously not true.Anyone know why? I don't want to have less storage than I do in real life, I want to have the ability to use all available storage.

On the other hand... I think it's root that has 54GB, although I still don't get how root has it's own storage.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have divided your storage space into two filesystems:

- 54GB on a logical volume called `root`, mounted at `/`;
- 258GB on a logical volume called `home`, presumably mounted at `/home`.

The screenshot in the second picture in your answer is not for “Computer Properties”, but “`/` Properties”. It shows the used and free space on the filesystem that contains the directory `/` (root directory).

The division of the storage space was made when you installed the system. Having separate volumes for the system and for user files is a common choice, and the filesystem sizes make sense (maybe `/` is a little on the big side). There's nothing to worry about.

If you're used to Windows: you have a `C:` and a `D:` drive, the 54GB one is just `C:`.

Comment: Thanks!I hoped it was the issue. I am new to Fedora so they partition things differently. Glad to hear your answer.